# Google App Engine - How to do a reverse dns lookup for push notifications

Tags: python, google-app-engine, push-notification, dns

Per docs: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/apis-google

Is there a way to do a DNS lookup within Google App Engine?

I've tried sockets ([Python lookup hostname from IP with 1 second timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575760/python-lookup-hostname-from-ip-with-1-second-timeout)), but GAE doesn't support it. I've also tried resolver, but I'm getting a timeout error, even though I set up timeout and lifetime ([Python Asynchronous Reverse DNS Lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093888/python-asynchronous-reverse-dns-lookups)).

Links included are examples of what I've tried, not the exact implementation (but pretty close to it!).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a paid app you have (restricted) access to sockets, so you can use the [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/) package.

Several related posts: [[google-app-engine] dnspython](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bgoogle-app-engine%5D%20dnspython)